# How to pan with the hand tool in Photoshop CS6 when the view is "Fit on screen"?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I would like to be able to pan an image while I'm seeing 100% of the image, but Photoshop doesn't allow me to do. Do you know any workarounds?

I'm using Windows.

Answer (score 10):

## With Photoshop CC

Simply tick the `Overscroll` option in the **Preferences**...

[image]

This may or may not be part of CS6 or early CC versions.. if you can't find it in the Preferences based upon the above screenshot... see below.

---

## original 2013 answer...

Tap the <kbd>F</kbd> key and enter full screen mode. You can pan to your heart's content.

There is also an optional plug in (apparently only available for the Macintosh) titled "[Overscroll Always](http://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/kb/plug-ins-photoshop-cs61.html)" which can be installed to allow panning at any time.

Comment: Well, but the plugin is not available for windows... :/

Comment: ooh ouch. I see that. I wasn't aware you were on a Windows system. I don't know what you can do in that case other than full screen mode.

Answer (score 3):

Scott provided the right answer for latest Photoshop versions: *Overscroll* option in *Preferences > tools*.

At last.. Many thanks Adobe for this nice option and @Scott for showing it to us.

**Original answer**

Five years after the question was posted, this simple functionallity isn't available yet, at least in standard screen mode.

As you can't pan the image, the only thing you can do is undock the window and move it around.

In full screen mode you can pan, but windows taskbar and all other opened files in photoshop disappear, which is awkward in many cases.

Answer (score -1):

There is a fix for that (for Windows!!!) here:
https://forums.adobe.com/message/4911152#4911152

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Graphic Design. Could you please edit your answer to include a summary of what you linked to? If the link goes away in the future, this answer would no longer be useful.